# SharePoint 2013 multilingual text based on regional settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, multilingual

I have a SharePoint 2013 site with custom newsfeed webpart. The news items are retrieved from a Custom SharePoint list. I want to change the header of the webpart to different language based on the regional settings. For example, If I change the regional settings of computer to German I want to change display webpart heading in German in SharePoint site.

Is it possible to do using resource files for each language.

Answer (score 0):

"However, not all user interface elements are displayed in the secondary, preferred language. The following list includes examples of items that are not supported by the multilingual user interface: Web Parts (except those that are linked to lists or libraries)"

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805062(v=office.14).aspx